# How to pass RGB in one entry as separate arguments to a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a code that user enters RGB values in 3 separate entry and by clicking a button it converts it to HSV by calling a function.
Picture is what i have now.
Now for next step, I want RGB to be entered in ONE entry and still be passed to function as 3 separate argument. for ex:
R,G,B[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7UJ9.jpg)

Comment: You've told us what you want but you haven't asked a question. What do you need help with? What is preventing you from doing what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the values separated by commas as a string in the entry box, extract the values using string manipulation, then pass them to your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. (`contents` is an example of the entry window contents)

```
In [1]: contents = '100,75,255'
Out[1]: '100,75,255'

In [2]: R, G, B = [int(j) for j in contents.split(',')]

In [3]: R, G, B
Out[3]: (100, 75, 255)
```

Comment: can you explain 3rd line please., I get what it does, dont get how it assigns it to R,G,B

Comment: in this case if User only enters 2 input, It will errors out. it would be an interesting challenge to check if there is 3 integer input, otherwise, ask user to enter them completely.

Comment: @bigly That's trivial; just wrap it in a `try`/`except ValueError`. That will *also* cover the case where one of the values isn't an integer.